# How to perform a cross-hierarchy call in C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, refactoring

I am working on a simple GUI framework, and I faced a problem calling protected virtual methods.

Here is the `IKeyboardInputListenerService` interface of service I use to receive keyboard events and the `Control` class that represents a base for all my GUI controls. The internal method is the one being refactored.

```
public interface IKeyboardInputListenerService
{
    event EventHandler<KeyboardEventArgs> KeyPressed;
}

public abstract class Control
{
    public IKeyboardInputListenerService KeyboardInputListenerService { get; }

    protected Control(IKeyboardInputListenerService keyboardInputListenerService) =>
        KeyboardInputListenerService = keyboardInputListenerService;

    public event EventHandler<KeyboardEventArgs> KeyPressed;

    /* protected */ internal virtual void OnKeyPressed(object sender, KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
        if (enabled && visible && focused && !args.Suppressed)
        {
            KeyPressed?.Invoke(sender, args);
            args.Suppressed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Activate() =>
        KeyboardInputListenerService.KeyPressed += new EventHandler<KeyboardEventArgs>(OnKeyPressed);
}
```

I also created a `ContainerControl` class that is supposed to contain child controls(like the `Panel` or `GroupBox` in Windows Forms) and that overrides the virtual method:

```
public abstract class ContainerControl : Control
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Control> controls;

    protected ContainerControl(IKeyboardInputListenerService keyboardInputListenerService)
        : base(keyboardInputListenerService) =>
        controls = new ObservableCollection<Control>();

    /* protected */ internal override void OnKeyPressed(object sender, KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls)
            control.OnKeyPressed(sender, args);

        base.OnKeyPressed(sender, args);
    }
}
```

Problem is, I cannot decide which modifier to use for methods such as `OnKeyPressed`. I wanted to make them `protected`, but it causes a compiler error:

> Error CS1540 Cannot access protected member 'Control.OnKeyPressed(object, KeyboardEventArgs)' via a qualifier of type 'Control'; the qualifier must be of type 'ContainerControl' (or derived from it)

I can make them `public`, but I do not really think it is a good idea, because there is no reason for it except for resolving the problem caused by a cross-hierarchy call. I made them `internal`, but there is also a drawback: if anyone will want to create a user control, they will not be able to receive events, so the control will be useless.

**The question is** how to get access from a derived class to virtual methods of the base class without making the methods public-accessed.

Comment: As @Olivier Jacot-Descombes said, the `protected internal` modifier is the way to go. But even without a `protected internal` modifier, you could've had the modifier as `protected` and another `internal` method defined in `Control` class just to forward the call to the initial `OnKeyPressed`. E.g.: `internal void Control.OnKeyPressedCall(...) => this.OnKeyPressed(...)`. I think, in fact, that `protected internal` is just syntax sugar for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `protected internal`

```
protected internal virtual void OnKeyPressed(object sender, KeyboardEventArgs args)
{ ... }
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) says:

> **protected internal** The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in which it is declared, or from within a derived class in another assembly.